# Git Repository On Laptop

Tags: git

In error I initialized my laptop as a repository. How do I delete this setting? I am having issues cloning repo's from site to LT.

Comment: What Command did you execute?

Comment: remove the `.git` file at the root level of the repo

Comment: Command used "git init".

Answer (score 1):

> Command used "git init"

If you mistakingly used git int at the root folder of your laptop (`/` or `C:\`), it should have created an hidden folder `.git`.
All you need to do is to delete it, in order for the rest of your disk not to be considered as part of a git repo.